# React small project issue

Tags: reactjs, axios

My axios request finishes already after i rerender my component and logic is broken!

Here is my fetchData method:

```js
fetchData = () => {    // runs only once!! on the button click LOAD QUESTIONS
  console.log('[Game] fetchData method received url: ' + this.state.apiUrl);
  axios.get(this.state.apiUrl).then((response) => {
    console.log('[Game] fetchdata before setState , datapackage' + response.data.results)
    this.setState({
      dataPackage: response.data.results,
      fetched: true,
    });
    console.log("[Game] fetchData method ran");
    this.showQuestion();
  });
}
```

Here is my render condition in render method and it doesn't work this way:

```js
if (this.state.dataPackage) { // rendering select menu before populating the state! 
  mainQuestion = <MainQ currentQuestion={this.state.currentQuestion} />; // if we do have a datapackage - show current question 
}
```

Comment: here is my render condition in render method and it doesn't work this way:
if (this.state.dataPackage) {   // rendering select menu before populating the state!
      mainQuestion = <MainQ currentQuestion={this.state.currentQuestion} />; // if we do have a datapackage - show current question
    }

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can edit your post--that's hard to understand as a comment. When you say "logic is broken", what does that entail exactly?

Comment: Try this in your return  `this.state.dataPackage &&  <MainQ currentQuestion={this.state.currentQuestion} />`

Comment: I have it resolved!! just wasn't sure that I could return a completely different value if my request is not finished yet.. Just added a condition and I am returning a spinner while my axios request returns value and populates my state. Thank you guys!